British interwar period movie - woman who goes to work for a family in rural England
It's a British movie made in the last 20 years, and I believe it's set in the Interwar years. I think the main character is a woman who goes to work for a family in rural England and there's a subplot where she falls in love with the married man of the family. 
He's the only character I remember really well: he has this huge guilt complex because he was an officer in the war and lost his entire unit, which was most of the other men in town. Also I think he's envious of this other guy from the same area who brought back all his men. Maybe it was after the Second World War, but I'm pretty sure it was in the Interwar period. Also I think he works on motorcycles. 
I seem to remember the movie had comedic elements but I'm not sure if it was more comedy, drama, or romance overall. Setting wise it reminded me of Gosford Park and Downton Abbey.

Please don't use weird formatting. It messes everything up.
